Neo4j Relationship Existence Query Have too Many DB Hits
I have a query that retrieves 1,500 customers and a promotion with a specific ID. The query then checks if those customers do not have this promotion.
My problem is that the query results in too many database hits at this step, around 120,000 hits:
WHERE NOT (customers)-[:HAS_PROMOTION]->(promo)

Here's the query
PROFILE
MATCH(promo:Promotion{id: "XXXX"})
WHERE promo.end_time > timestamp()
MATCH (c:Customer)
WITH promo, c AS customers SKIP 9000 LIMIT 1500
WHERE NOT (customers)-[:HAS_PROMOTION]->(promo)
RETURN customers.id

First part of profile
Second part of profile
I tried to use exists function and it didn't make any difference
and I also inverted the relation direction and it got faster by around 10%

How many Customer nodes are there? Can you filter Customer in some way? Maybe you could check if "last login" is within some time range (so, if you haven't seen the customer since the start of the promotion, don't even check for the relationship later in the query), or find some other logical way to reduce the set of customers to consider in the query. As written, MATCH (c:Customer) must evaluate every Customer (within your LIMIT 1500 clause) to see if it has / doesn't have :HAS_PROMOTION. Also, why is it a problem to have 120,000 database hits? How many are you trying to achieve?

Depending on your data, it may be more efficient to first get all promoted customers, and then just return all other customers. For example:
MATCH(promo:Promotion{id: "XXXX"})<-[:HAS_PROMOTION]-(pc:Customer)
WHERE promo.end_time > timestamp()
WITH COLLECT(ID(pc)) AS promotedCustomers
MATCH (c:Customer)
WHERE NOT ID(c) IN promotedCustomers
RETURN c.id


It had the same performance unfortunately
